# file not found VBA

Tags: vba, excel, kill

I am having a frustrating time trying to do create a backup script in VBA. I get an error 'File not found' when trying to kill a file after opening it, making a backup and saving it under a new name.

```
Application.Workbooks.Open Old
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Archive
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs New

'If Len(Dir$(Old)) > 0 Then Kill Old
If Len(Dir$(Old)) = 0 Then MsgBox ("bleuh")
'Here is where I get the message "Bleuh" even though Old was just opened a few lines ago..
```

The first line works fine, but when I want to kill the file 'Old', I get the error. Hence, I tried to test whether the file existed. The result was the Msg "Bleuh". So the file can be opened, but not found a few lines later. Can anyone explain this and help me?

In order to be complete, the entire code is found down here.

```
Sub UpdateAll()
Dim Afk As String, J As String, NJ As String, Path As String, strFile As String, Old As String, Archive As String, New As String
'Dim fso As Object

Path = "C:\Users\Name\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Testing backup" & "\"

Year = Year(Date)
VJ = Year
NJ = Year + 1


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'test for Afk (I define Afk for some additional functions that are not relevant for this problem)
Afk = "ABA"

'filenames
Old = Path & ("Planning ") & VJ & Space(1) & Afk
Archive = Path & ("Planning\Archive ") & VJ & Space(1) & Afk
New = Path & ("Planning ") & NJ & Space(1) & Afk

Application.Workbooks.Open Old
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Archive
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs New

If Len(Dir$(Oud)) > 0 Then Kill Old
If Len(Dir$(Oud)) = 0 Then MsgBox ("bleuh")
'Here is where I get the message "Bleuh" even though Old was just opened a few lines ago..

'Also tried
'fso.CopyFile Old, Archive 'AND
'FileCopy Old, Archive

'in combination with: 

'Name Old As New
' "SSDD"

'Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your filename variable have an extension on it?

Comment: I'm not seeing where you assign a path and filename to `Oud`.

Comment: You're deleting the file first and then verifying if it still exists... Try a `Select Case` instead...

Comment: Surely `New` is a reserved word and it hasn't been defined, unless you mean `Nieuw` in which case you've got a typo.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry everybody, I translated all the words I used in Dutch to English just to make it more understandable for everybody, but I made some typo's in the post. I think I cleaned it up again. Furthermore, I did not put the ' in front of the line 'If Len(Dir$(Old)) > 0 Then Kill Old. Last point, they are all .xlsx files. I've tried with and without extension. Same result

Comment: As @braX said - your old path is `"C:\Users\Name\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Testing backup\Planning 2017 ABA"`.  Have you tried adding `.xlsx` on the end (not sure it's needed though).  Also, and I assume you have as it's saving - you do have the required permissions to delete from the folder?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I tried with and without extensions with the same result. However, I am actually not sure about the required permission. I can manually delete files from the folder, so I assumed I should be able to delete them through VBA. Could it be possible that I need some type of permission? Is there a way to check whether this causes the problem? I would have expected an error "permission denied" instead of "file not found", however.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your code I realized you don't need to open your file ('cause you don't get any information from it). You just want to move it. So, try the following:

```
Name Old as Archive
```

This should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks for the help, although it does not solve the problem. I get the same error 'file not found'.

Comment: Could you verify with a `MsgBox Old` command if the file path and name is really correct? And if the file is really in the folder you specify?

Comment: I verified it with a msgbox that the name is correct, and checked visually whether the file is in the specified folder. Also, the file opens in the line Application.Workbooks.Open Old, so I am really quite sure the file path and name are correct